# Finding GCD of Array Code C language

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, greatest-common-divisor

I am trying to write a program in C. The program is supposed to find the GCD (greatest common divisor) of a given array. I am trying to use the smallest number of the array to find the GCD. I was wondering whats wrong with my last loop. I havent figured a way on how to check if the division is giving any decimal points in order to stop the loop. This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int A[10]={112, 160, 180, 240, 288, 32, 480, 96, 60, 72};
    int i;
    int j;
    int minimum = A[0];
    int GCD;
    int temp;

    for (i=1;i<9;i++)
    {
        if( A[i] < minimum)
        {
            minimum = A[i];
        }
    }

    for (i=1; i < minimum/2; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 9;j++)
        {
            GCD = 2*i;
            temp = ((A[j])/(GCD));
            int check = temp%1;
            if (check == 0)
                break;
        }
    }

    printf("The Greates Common Denominator is: %d", GCD);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note the `temp % 1` will always be zero.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler what would be the correct way to check for decimals??

Comment: Since you're storing results in `int` variables, there won't be any 'decimals' (assuming you mean fractional numbers).

Comment: I don't think you need to find the smallest number.  You can calculate: `int g = a[0]; for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) { g = gcd(a[i], g); }` should work fine (where `gcd()` is a function to calculate the GCD of two numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned gcd(unsigned x, unsigned y){
    unsigned wk;
    if(x<y){ wk=x;x=y;y=wk; }
    while(y){
        wk = x%y;
        x=y;
        y=wk;
    }
    return x;
}

int gcd_a(int n, int a[n]){
    if(n==1) return a[0];
    if(n==2) return gcd(a[0], a[1]);
    int h = n / 2;
    return gcd(gcd_a(h, &a[0]), gcd_a(n - h, &a[h]));
}

int main(void){
    int A[10]={112, 160, 180, 240, 288, 32, 480, 96, 60, 72};
    int size_A = sizeof(A)/sizeof(*A);
    int gcd = gcd_a(size_A, A);
    printf("%d\n", gcd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Clever recursion; does it save anything compared with simple iteration?  It looks to me like it is going to do the same number of GCD calculations, but uses extra stack space (not a significant factor, for the most part).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  by simple loop probably good. Stack is also required extra. I think as there is not much merit.

Comment: There is a possibility that the advantage of this method (can be rewritten in a simple loop) can be reduced to the remainder calculation. e.g. this case my 15, your 21.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int gcd(int x, int y)
{
    int r;

    if (x <= 0 || y <= 0)
        return(0);

    while ((r = x % y) != 0)
    {
        x = y;
        y = r;
    }
    return(y);
}

int main(void)
{
    int A[10] = { 112, 160, 180, 240, 288, 32, 480, 96, 60, 72 };
    int g = A[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        g = gcd(g, A[i]);

    printf("The Greatest Common Denominator is: %d\n", g);

    return 0;
}
```

The answer is 4.  This is clearly correct; it is the GCD of 32 and 60; everything else is divisible by 4.

If desired, you could optimize the loop with:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < 10 && g != 1; i++)
        g = gcd(g, A[i]);
```

When the GCD is `1`, it won't get any bigger,

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    int r;
    while(a)
    {
        r=b%a;
        b=a;
        a=r;
    }
    return b;
}
int gcd_(int* A, int N)
{
    int c=gcd(*A,*(A+1));
    int i,g;
    for(i=1;i<N-1;i++)
    {
        g=gcd(c,*(A+1+i));
        c=g;
    }
    return c;
}
int main(void)
{
    int A[]={96,60,32,72,84,90};
    int N=sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);
    int t=gcd_(A,N);
    printf("%d",t);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

int gcd(int a, int b){
int t;
while(a)
{
    t = a;
    a = b%a;
    b = t;
}
return b;
}

int main(){
int n;
cout<<"how many numbers (Max 10): "; // your choice
cin>>n;
cin.ignore();
cout<<endl;
int arr[n-1];

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {

  cin>>arr[i];

}
int ans;

ans = arr[0];
for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
    ans = gcd(ans,arr[j]);
}
cout<<"GCD = "<<ans;


//cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

  int main() {
        int i, j, n, flag = 0, small, *data;

        /* get the number of inputs from the user */
        printf("Enter the number of inputs:");
        scanf("%d", &n);

        /* allocate memory to store n numbers */
        data = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * n);

        /* get n numbers from the user */
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                printf("Data[%d]: ", i);
                scanf("%d", &data[i]);
        }

        /* find the smallest of n numbers */
        small = data[0];
        for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
                if (data[i] < small)
                        small = data[i];
        }

        /*
         * use the smallest no to find gcd of n numbers.
         * Start checking from small to 1 whether the 
         * same value divides all the given inputs
         */
        for (i = small; i > 0; i--) {
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                        if (data[j] % i != 0) {
                                flag = 1;
                        }
                }
                /* print the result */
                if (!flag) {
                        printf("GCD of given %d numbers is %d\n", n, i);
                        break;
                }
                flag = 0;
        }

        return 0;
  }
```

Comment: You may consider adding a little bit explanation on why your code works for OP; Make sure you add relevant code parts

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int x;

void main()
{
  int i,num[10]={0};
  printf("How many numbers do you want to enter =");
  scanf("%d",&x);
  for(i=0;i<x;i++)
  scanf("%d",& num[i]);
  printf("The hcf of the numbers are = %d ", hcf(num));

 }

 int hcf(int num[])
 {
   int count,rem,lv,i,j;
   lv=gnum(num);
   if(lv==1)
     return 1;

 for(j=2;j<=lv;j++)
 {
       count =0;

        for(i=0;i<x;i++)
     {
         rem = num[i]%j ;

         if( rem != 0 || num[i]< j )
          break;

         else
           {
             count++;
           }

    }

    if(count == x)
        {
         for(i=0;i<x;i++)
          num[i]=num[i]/j;
          return(j*hcf(num));
        }


 }

 if(count!= x)
    return 1;

}

  int  gnum(int num[])
 {
    int i,temp=num[0];
      for(i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
      if(temp >= num[i])
      temp = num[i];
    }

     return (temp);
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Just a few tips: you should comment your code explaining the changes you made and why it works. Also it helps if you stick to the changes required by the user. For instance, it confuses me that now there's an input required instead of the original input array.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
 {
int A[2] = {10,30};
int a,b,r,i;
for ( i = 1; i < 2; i++)
{
 a=A[0],b=A[i];
  while(b!=0)
  {

   r=a%b;/*remainder*/
   a=b;
   b=r;
 }
}
printf("The Greatest Common Denominator is: %d\n", a);
return 0;

}

/*You can change the **for** loop range according to the array values*\
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int A[10]={112, 160, 180, 240, 288, 32, 480, 96, 60, 72};
    int i;
    int j;
    int minimum = A[0];
    int GCD;
    int temp;
    int f;
    for (i=1;i<10;i++)
    {
        if( A[i] < minimum)
        {
            minimum = A[i];
        }
    }

    for (i=1; i <= minimum; i++)
    {
        f=0;
        for (j = 0; j < 10;j++)
        {

            if(A[j]%i!=0)
            {
               f=1; 
               break;
            }



        }
        if(f==0)
         GCD=i;
    }

    printf("The Greates Common Denominator is: %d ", GCD);

    return 0;
}

    enter code here
```